# My app is now dockerized - but how can I add a base image (eg alpine) using docker-compose? - or, should I do this at all?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have created a PHP web-application (LAMP) and now I have made it available to be used with docker-compose. All this works fine for me, but when I test it, my machine delivers the host system, Ubuntu 18.04. How can I easily make the application usable for Windows or MAC users as well?

A. Should I add a small base image (eg alpine:3.9) to the package (is there a simple way to add this with docker-compose)?

or:

B) No need to do so: A Windows or Mac user can add the base image easily.

If the latter:

- a) what are the steps needed then?
  and
- b) how can I do the same and force docker to use that base-image instead the Linux kernel from my host? (I have just started to rebuild it all with alpine:3.9 - but when I "docker exec -it mywebapp /bin/bash" a:
- uname -a

or

- cat /proc/version

do both show me the host's Ubuntu/ kernel information instead of the alpine's one (which would be the 4.19)

if somebody wants to have a look and give me some advice to improve it, I'll really appreciate it..
(its all in the latest zip at https://sourceforge.net/projects/c-c-s/)

Within the docker-compose.yml I do have 4 Services:

- 3 for the databases (each with a build: context: ./dbfolder_index - and a simple Dockerfile there containing only "FROM mariadb:10.4")
- 1 for the PHP-written web-app, containing the Dockerfile with the FROM php:7.2-apache and a lot of RUNs and COPYs for generating the SSL-cert, cp the apache2.conf giving permissions to the web-app's upload-folders and so on.

if needed: the docker-compose.yml content (for one database & for the web-app)

```
{
version: '3' 
services:    
  metadb:
    container_name: metadb
    build:   
      context: ./metadbmetadb:
    container_name: metadb

    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: toor123xyz
      MYSQL_DATABASE: meta_db
      MYSQL_USER: admin123 
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: adminpw123

    logging:
      driver: syslog
      options:
        tag: "{{.DaemonName}}(image={{.ImageName}};name={{.Name}};id={{.ID}})"

    restart: on-failure
    ports: 
      - "3400:3306"
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./metadb/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./metadb/sqlconf:/etc/mysql/conf.d

    networks:
      - default
## (.. 2 more databases for the projects.. )
## start web app

  web:
    hostname: localhost
    container_name: ccs
    build:
      context: ./phpapacheall
    image: cyconet/ccs_0.9.7
    volumes:
      - ./projectdb1/cdata:/var/www/html/project1/cdata
      - ./projectdb2/cdata:/var/www/html/project2/cdata
      - ./phpapacheall/init-scripts/:/init-scripts/
    command:
      - /init-scripts/cdata-chown-script.sh
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8400:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - metadb
    links:
      - metadb
      - projectdb1
      - projectdb2
    networks:
      - default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application is not yet "dockerized", you only simplified the build process of Docker image of your application.

Next step is to build the image and to deploy it to Docker Hub. After that the end-users could download your application and run it locally using pure Docker commands or provided docker-compose file.

Your docker-compose.yml file is not suitable for end-users, because "metadb" is missing "image" parameter and all containers are referring to "build directory".

Comment: Im sorry that you did not understand my question.

Comment: Im sorry that you did not understand my question.
(btw: application runs fine. Users do download it - and all they have to do is unzip, cd to that directory & type: 
docker-compose up --build
and voila: typing localhost into the browsers address-bar redirects to https://localhost - without a prior exchange of the ssl-certification, users need to bypass the warning - and what they see next is the beautiful login-form of the CCS project collaboration suite). ... if their host is running a Linux, of course (docker can use that kernel then..))

Comment: I understand that your users can BUILD your project locally, but that is not the way an applications packages into Docker containers are usually distributed. A more common way to distribute them is to build Docker image and PUBLISH them to Docker Hub or other Docker repository like Amazon ECR. After that users will download Docker images and run them on their computers.

Comment: If you follow that path, then it will not matter at all, what operation system is used by the user of your application.